# How to specify entries per page at runtime

Tags: flask-admin

I'm using flask-admin and SQLAlchemy backend. It is possible to alter the entries per page in the source code, like this:

```
class ModulesView(sqla.ModelView):
    page_size = 250
```

But it would be great to be able to change that number at runtime, as a query parameter, i.e. http://localhost:5000/admin/module/?page_size=10.

Please advise if it's possible to change it at runtime. I've got an ugly idea to override _get_list_extra_args and set page_size there, but I'm looking for a better solution. Or maybe there's another way you use, better than query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my solution was as follows:

```
class PageView(sqla.ModelView):
    def _get_list_extra_args(self):
        args = super()._get_list_extra_args()
        new_page_size = request.args.get('max', 0, type=int)
        if new_page_size > 0:
            args.extra_args['max'] = new_page_size
            self.page_size = new_page_size

        return args
```

Probably not as nice as creating a filter, but at least it works as expected, and reusable for all models.